# Front-End Mail Client on wordpress?Possible?

Tags: wordpress, email, frontend

I have a wish to somehow create on front-end a page with webmail client, to access up to 20+ email accounts, also send/recieve emails, etc. Like Thunderbird, or any other email client but on web. I didn't found any plugin for this purpose and maybe you have some ideas how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be extremely hard if you wish to build from scratch. My best guess is that you need to find an open-source email client and integrate it within the WP framework. But that also will be hard to do, finding an open-source email client will save a ton and tons of time to build a strong email client but you're going to have to customize its structure to make compatible with WordPress environment, like database calls, authentication and more.
Still, you can always build a simple email client that checks the client email server grab his emails, and send an email if they want to, this is possible using the POP, SMTP PHP functionalities that allows you to talk to the email server.

Thanks